# Using accelerometer code in a separate class

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors

Hi Im trying to use a different java class for accelerometer usage so it can be called from another class to manipulate results. such as doing calculations using accelerometer class object.Following class does not have a view. I have done the below code with completed methods when an layout was assigned to it. Please tell me how to use the accelerometer class without a layout so i can call from another class.
(I dont want to use the **on create method** since im not using a view)
Thank you

```
package com.example.vehiclecollisiondetection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class AccelerometerClass extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.
```

**IDE gives an error here "Syntax error on token, misspelled construct and code hinting does not detect for sm. object**

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


    }



}
```

**I figured out that i need to use OnCreate method. But is there anyway to use the code without a layout? (calling from another class)**

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be deriving from Activity.   All you need to do is implement SensorEventListener  and be registered for the sensor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, 
I tried registering the the listener but ADT does not detect code hinting and gives the above error given in the code snippet.

Comment: I figured out that i need to use OnCreate method. But is there anyway to use the code without a layout? (calling from another class)

Comment: You need to understand what an activity is.  If you want to use this from another class, it cannot be an Activity.